# Solution of equality $N'(t)=f(N(t)) N(t)$ have the following property: $\lim_{t\to\infty} N(t)=K$- proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, mathematical-modeling

Check that if $f$ is such a differentiable and strictly increasing function that $f(K)=0$, then the solution of equality $N'(t)=f(N(t)) N(t)$ have the following property: $\lim_{t\to\infty} N(t)=K$.

It's the fact that $N'(t)>0$, when $N(t)<K$,

and $N'(t)<0$, when $N(t)>K$.

The problem is kind of relates to Verhulst Model.

I need help with this exercise, any will be appreciated.

Comment: Assuming $N$ is continuously differentiable and does have a limit as $t \to \infty$, that limit must be $0$ or $K$. Indeed, $N'$ must either tend to $0$ (if the limit is approached monotonically either from above or below) or must hit $0$ infinitely often as $t \to \infty$ (otherwise), so either infinitely often $N(t) f(N(t)) = 0$, or $N(t) f(N(t)) \to 0$. Since $f$ has exactly one root, that means either "$N = K$ or $N = 0$ infinitely often" or "$N \to K$ or $N \to 0$". Note that $N(t) = 0$ is a solution of your equation, so you can't do better than that.